# Serial communication in C using Loopback on cable

Tags: c, serial-port

I'm trying to create a simple Serial communication in C. I'm having some problems when receiving the data. I appears that the buffer size is not correct, or the data is not being retrieved from the Serial.

This is how I have created the code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define BUFFERLENGTH 256

int main () {
    
    HANDLE comm;
    BOOL wComm;
    char buf[] = "abcd1234 \r\n";
    DWORD dwNoBytesToWrite = sizeof(buf);
    DWORD dwNoBytesWritten = 0;

    BOOL Read_Status;                     
    DWORD dwEventMask;
    char SerialBuffer[BUFFERLENGTH+1];
    char finalStr[BUFFERLENGTH+1] = "";
    DWORD NoBytesRead; 
    int i = 0;

    comm = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\COM7", 
                                            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, //Read/Write
                      0,                            // No Sharing
                      NULL,                         // No Security
                      OPEN_EXISTING,// Open existing port only
                      0,            // Non Overlapped I/O
                      NULL); 

    if (comm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      printf("Error in opening serial port");
  else
      printf("opening serial port successful");
// set short timeouts on the comm port.
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
    if (!SetCommTimeouts(comm, &timeouts))
        printf("setting port time-outs.");

//Config
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

    Write_Status = GetCommState(comm, &dcbSerialParams);     //retreives  the current settings

    if (Write_Status == FALSE) {
        printf("\n   Error! in GetCommState()");
        CloseHandle(comm);
        return 1;
    }

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_57600;      // Setting BaudRate = 9600
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;             // Setting ByteSize = 8
                                              //dcbSerialParams.
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;    // Setting StopBits = 1
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = ODDPARITY;      // Setting Parity = None

    // Write Serial
    wComm = WriteFile(
        comm,
        buf,
        dwNoBytesToWrite,
        &dwNoBytesWritten,
        NULL
    );

    if (!wComm) 
    {
        printf("Problem writing to comm");
    }

    // MASK 

    Read_Status = SetCommMask(comm, EV_RXCHAR); 

    if (Read_Status == FALSE)
        printf("\n\nError! in Setting CommMask");
    else
        printf("\n\nSetting CommMask successfull");

    // WAITING DATA

    printf("\n\nWaiting for Data Reception");

    Read_Status = WaitCommEvent(comm, &dwEventMask, NULL); 

    if (Read_Status == FALSE)
    {
        printf("\n Error! in Setting WaitCommEvent()");
    }
    else
    {
        //fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n\nCharacters Received\n");

        do
        {
            if (ReadFile(comm, SerialBuffer, BUFFERLENGTH, &NoBytesRead, NULL))
            {
                
            printf("%c", SerialBuffer[i]);
                strcat(finalStr, SerialBuffer[i]); 
                
                i++;
            }
        } while (NoBytesRead > 0);
    }

  CloseHandle(comm);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is what I'm receiving as the response:

[image]

Comment: Did you consider the transmission time of serial communication? You are receiving one event for the first character, fetch that, but the second character has not yet been received, so your program stops correctly as programmed.

Comment: @thebusybee But how would I fix that? I'm passing the right lenght int NoBytesRead, it should loop throught that

Comment: I have added the DCB config to it

Comment: How would you act as a human if you want to received a message character by character, and you don't know how fast they arrive? How do you know when the message is complete? Apply your algorithm, there are multiple ways to do it. Timeouts, a specific protocol, a certain number of characters, you name it.

Comment: @thebusybee Apparently it worked adding timeouts, but I got my string printed twice, you know why?

Comment: Would you mind to show the expected and the actual output, please? [Edit] your question for addition. Obviously incrementing `i` in the loop is an error, because `ReadFile()` always starts storing at index 0. And I'm missing some code to ensure that the received characters have a `'\0'` (end-of-string marker) at the end after the last received character. I don't think that `ReadFile()` adds this for you.

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF `printf("%c", SerialBuffer[i]); strcat(finalStr, SerialBuffer[i]);` is wrong. If `ReadFile()` is successful, it has written `NoBytesRead` number of bytes into `SerialBuffer`. so print out the entire `SerialBuffer` up to `NoBytesRead` number of `char`s, not 1 `char` (and certainly not an indexed `char`). But you can't use `strcat()` since `SerialBuffer` is not null-terminated. And more importantly, `SerialBuffer` and `finalStr` are the same size, so if you are reading `SerialBuffer` in a loop and appending to `finalStr`, you are going to quickly overflow `finalStr`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Could you formulate that in an answer please! I didn't get the printing part too well